# how to remove repeating elements in an array using LINQ?remove an element if its repeating?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
int [] n=new int[10]{2,3,33,33,55,55,123,33,88,234};
output=2,3,123,88,234;
```

use LINQ
i can do it using two for loops by continuously checking.but i need a more simple way using LINQ

**its not removing duplicates..**
removing duplicates by distinct will give  =  2,3,123,33,55,88,234
my output should be                        =  2,3,123,,88,234;

Comment: How about Distinct() ??

Comment: adding the example of what you wanted exactly should have been done initially...

Comment: pleas be sure about the questions...its not just removing duplicates..

Comment: i have added the output i wanted..its different from the answer given in removing duplicates

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: var dupe = n.GroupBy(s => s) .SelectMany(grp => grp.Skip(1)).Distinct().ToArray(); 

int[] f = n.Except(dupe ).ToArray();

this is how i tried..

Answer (score 6):

I combined your grouping idea and *matiash's* count. Not sure about its speed.

```
var result = n.GroupBy(s => s).Where(g => g.Count() == 1).Select(g => g.Key);
```

**Update:** i have measured the speed and it seems the time is linear, so you can use it on large collections

Comment: Congratulations, sir! This is way better :)

Comment: GroupBy should have O(n) complexity (see this question, it refers to SQL Group By operation, but the principle is the same). Filtering and selecting will also be O(n).

One note: when testing the performance of answers (and Linq queries in general), be sure to call ToArray() or ToList() at the end. Most of Linq methods use yield internally, so the real computation can be deffered until you do an enumeration on the result. Calling ToArray() makes sure this enumeration happens and you measure the full running time.

Comment: linq for getting the most repeated word in a string?

Comment: @Lijo you should create a new question for this one. Comments are not an appropriate place.

Answer (score 4):

```
var result = n.Where(d => n.Count(d1 => d1 == d) <= 1);
```

This reads: only take those elements that are present at most 1 times in n.

It's quadratic though. Doesn't matter for short collections, but could possibly be improved.

**EDIT** [Dmitry's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24592740/82788) is linear, and hence far better.

Comment: make sure you heed the bit that says: "It's quadratic though"

Comment: can you explain i didnt got what you commented

Comment: its working  and this what i needed..oh.. i think if we use this for large collections it will be slow that what  you mean

Comment: @404 it means that the time needed will increase as the square of the number of items. In particular, for an input twice as large, it will take four times as long. So for _big_ collections it could be unwieldly.

Comment: I made an attempt at a slightly faster (alebit not compeltely pure LINQ) solution.